# X window (or whole linux system) replace Caps Lock with ESC *and* Control

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, input, accessibility

on windows there are several key maps applications that replaces <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> with ESC on a single 'press and relase' and with a Control signal if hold and another key is pressed.

Is there any way to do something similar on linux? Ideally on the whole system, but if it is only for X window it is fine too.

i'm currently writting scripts with the xautomation package tools. but i guess there is already a better way to do that via configurations.